# Recursively count specific files BASH

Tags: bash, recursion, file-type

My goal is to write a script to recursively search through the current working directory and the sub dirctories and print out a count of the number of ordinary files, a count of the directories, count of block special files, count of character special files,count of FIFOs, and a count of symbolic links. I have to use condition tests with [[ ]]. Problem is I am not quite sure how to even start.

I tried the something like the following to search for all ordinary files but I'm not sure how recursion exactly works in BASH scripting:

```
function searchFiles(){
    if [[ -f /* ]]; then
        return 1
    fi
}
searchFiles
echo "Number of ordinary files $?"
```

but I get 0 as a result. Anyone help on this?

Comment: where us the recursive call? and why recursion. Note that you would be able to only return a max value of 255 as the return value is limited by 1 byte (8 bit byte).

Comment: have a look at `pushd` and `popd`

Answer (score 42):

Why would you not use `find`?

```
$ # Files
$ find . -type f | wc -l
327
$ # Directories
$ find . -type d | wc -l
64
$ # Block special
$ find . -type b | wc -l
0
$ # Character special
$ find . -type c | wc -l
0
$ # named pipe
$ find . -type p | wc -l
0
$ # symlink
$ find . -type l | wc -l
0
```

Comment: I would love to, but we are told to specifically use the condition. But I will try to go off of this.

Comment: "we are told to" ... as in this is an assignment?

Comment: @Amanda: *this is an assignment" - Given that this was over a year ago, I think past tense would be more appropriate.

Comment: @MattH I was about to argue with you but ... right. It is indeed 2012.

Answer (score 3):

Something to get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash

directory=0
file=0
total=0

for a in *
do
   if test -d $a; then
      directory=$(($directory+1))
   else
      file=$(($file+1))
   fi

   total=$(($total+1))
   echo $a

done

echo Total directories: $directory
echo Total files: $file
echo Total: $total
```

No recursion here though, for that you could resort to `ls -lR` or similar; but then again if you are to use an external program you should resort to using `find`, that's what it's designed to do.

Comment: instead of `*` use `**` for recursion. `shopt globstar` has to be *on* for this to work. (`shopt -s globstar` to enable)