# Count files and folders in directory (ignore hidden files)

Tags: bash

This has probably answered before, but I cannot find it.

How do I count the files and directories in a directory without including subdirectories? Also, hidden files should be ignored (because this folder is a git repo).

More precisely, I need an if clause, that the current folder only has one file (namely "script.sh") and no sub-folders with the exception of .git/ .

How can I do this in Bash?

EDIT: In contrast to [Recursively count specific files BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268863), I want to ignore the .git folder and I do not want to count files and folders in subfolders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` should help:

```
if [ "$(cd /some/dir && find * -maxdepth 0 -type f)" == "script.sh" ]; then
```

`*` will list only non hidden files and `maxdepth` won't search subdirectories.