# Bash program for counting certain type of files in directory using functions not showing any numbers

Tags: bash, shell

My program needs to search all non-hidden files in the directory for a file and look for its permissions when the user enters the name of the file as an argument like so:

```
./search.sh file*
```

And then displays the number of files with that name and certain permissions. The problem is that when I input a file name the program shows no numbers at all.
Any help will be much appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

oRE()
{
  find . -type f -readable -executable -name "$1" | wc -l
}

nonEx()
{
  num=0
  num=$(find . -type f -name "$1" | wc -l)
  if [[ $num -eq 0 ]];
   then
      echo 1
  else
      echo $num
  fi
}

dir()
{
  find "$1" -maxdepth 0 -type d | wc -l
}

oR()
{
  find . -type f -readable -name "$1" | wc -l
}

tByt()
{
  wc -c < "$1"
}

if [[ "$#" -eq 1 ]];
 then
   echo normal, readable, and executable     : $(oRE "$1")
   echo does not exist                       : $(nonEx "$1")
   echo directory                            : $(dir "$1")
   echo normal and readable                  : $(oR "$1")
   echo total bytes in normal files          : $(tByt "$1")
fi
```

this is what I get:

```
 normal, readable, and executable     : 1
 does not exist                       : 2
find: `sample*': No such file or directory
 directory                            : 0
 normal and readable                  : 2
./search.sh: line 32: sample*: No such file or directory
 total bytes in normal files          :
```

Comment: You need to add `-name` before the `"$1"` in nonEx.

Comment: I added the `-name` now I get some numbers let me edit the code and post what i get

Comment: This is the problem if $1 contains a name of a non existing file: `wc -c < "$1"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively count specific files BASH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268863/recursively-count-specific-files-bash)

Answer (score 0):

Your command line to the script is going to expand to any matching files in the current directory as separate arguments. With more than one argument your script doesn't do anything because of the if statement. Try quoting the argument `'file*'`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried it like you said but it doesn't work

Comment: You probably need to quote the various `$1` in your program too as `"$1"`

Comment: same thing, no numbers

Comment: Are you getting any output at all? If not then your if test is not working and you should start debugging that first.